# Karma compiling Angular directive in test

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Hi I am trying to compile an Angular directive within a Karma test like so:

```
 describe("Midway: Testing My App", function() {
    var $compile, $rootScope;
    beforeEach(module('KSSApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(
        ['$compile','$rootScope', function($c, $r) {
        $compile = $c;
        $rootScope = $r;
        }]
    ));

    it("should compile the widget", function() {
       var element = $c('<My-app></My-app>')($r);
       console.log(element);
    });

});
```

This however just adds a `ng-scope` class to the element and does not compile the full directive.

Comment: This code is correct - does `KSSApp` define a directive within it that has a `template` or `templateUrl`?

Comment: @EdHinchliffe Yes, My-app has a template url.

Comment: @EdHinchliffe and that's the bit I want it to load.

Comment: Ok, are you using pre-compiled javascript templates, or is it just an HTML file?

Comment: @EdHinchliffe just html for the template files.

Comment: Ok, could you share the directive definition object? You can omit any `compile`/`link` functions if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to run a digest loop, plus I think you have inverted injected and testing variables (`$scompile` and `$rootScope`):

```
describe("Midway: Testing My App", function() {
    var $compile, $rootScope;
    beforeEach(module('KSSApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(
        ['$compile','$rootScope', function($c, $r) {
        $compile = $c;
        $rootScope = $r;
        }]
    ));

    it("should compile the widget", function() {
       // You're out of the inject function so I used full variable names
       var element = $compile('<My-app></My-app>')($rootScope);

       // run a digest loop
       $rootScope.$digest();
       console.log(element);
    });

});
```